# Assign class to element if it contains a child

Tags: jquery

I have many elements with the same class, and I want to check if some of them has a specific child, anb if it does, assign a special class to that element.

I tried this:

```
if ( $('li.first_li').find('ul.multi-menu') ) alert('code');
```

And it does alert it, meaning it has a match.

But how do I assign a class to `li.first_li` that has this child? The following does not work.

```
if ( $('li.first_li').find('ul.multi-menu') ) $(this).addClass('code');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [**.has()**](http://api.jquery.com/has/) method.

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant that matches the selector or DOM element.

Use

```
$('li.first_li').has('ul.multi-menu').addClass('code')
```

Comment: this is funny :) you both have the same answer at the same time :D

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [`.has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) filter at this context to achieve your need,

```
$('li.first_li').has('ul.multi-menu').addClass('code');
```

Comment: this is funny :) you both have the same answer at the same time :D

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen No I am 10 secs lagging behind.. :)